# Google analytics url link tracking

Tags: google-analytics

Lets say I want to advertise a link to a blog, app link etc, and I want to put that link on my business card using QR code.

Are there any services out there that I can attach a tag to the link so I would know if user runs the URL, it would know it came from the business card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UTM parameters are what you are looking for.

- This article gives a good overview of what UTM parameters are and how to use them.

  - https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863?hl=en
- You can also use this Campaign URL Builder created by Google Analytics.

  - https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/